# Set "default value" language for an app within Android Studio

Tags: android

I have an application and two main languages: English and German

The default language is English and if the user has set German as default language in the system settings, German is used instead.

I got this to work without any issue, but within the translation manager is shows me the following:
[image]

When looking at the flag in front of the "Default value" column, you can see, that the manager assumes, that the default language is German, which is wrong. So how can I tell the translation manager, which language the default language is?

Comment: what is default language of your system? and it should be working fine when you install app in device having default language as english

Comment: My default system language is german. So does Android Studio simple view the system language there? I mean, if you have multiple people working on  an app, each with a different system language, then this is not displayed correct at all...

Comment: if system language matches with any of the available locals of app then it would be highlighted as default , otherwise the language which is in values folder (without any qualifier) would be default language which is english in your case. So no need to worry about anything. It would work fine on all devices